# correct mocking of a service in angular using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Why does this test fail with: Expected null to be 'this is a party'.
I am trying to mock out the party service to return a fake value, but its not working.

```
'use strict';
describe("test controller: ConsultationService", function () {
    var scope;
    var controller;
    var partyService = {
        get: function() {}
    }

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('aureus'));
    beforeEach(function() {
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('partyService', partyService);
        });
    });
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q) {
        spyOn(partyService, 'get').and.callFake(function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve('this is a party');
            return deferred.promise;
        });
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('ConsultationController', { $scope: scope, $partyService: partyService });
    }));

    it("scope consultation should be defined", function () {
        expect(scope.consultation).toBe(null);
        expect(scope.party).toBe('this is a party');
    });
});
```

and this controller

```
aureus.controller('ConsultationController',
    ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 'ngProgress', 'partyService', 'ConsultationService',
    function ($scope, $location, $http, ngProgress, $partyService, consultationService) {
        $scope.consultation = null;
        $scope.party = null;
        $scope.urlData = Api.parseUrl($location.$$absUrl, '/comments/{account}');
        $partyService.get($scope.urlData.account).then(function (party) {
            $scope.party = party;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a `$scope.$digest` in your test when using deferreds.  Add this line to your test:

```
scope.$digest()
```

This will cause the deferred to actually resolve and your code will hit the `then` callback.